# Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0

Tags: android-studio-2.3

Hello all I am new as android developer. I am stuck into simple issue. I am getting `Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0` as logcat. I am not getting what to do !

Till now i was try to 'Invalid cache and restart' and re-bulid the project but not getting any sucess.

please guide me.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild project ?

Comment: I am already doing but not solve my issue.

Comment: okay means till now its not solved or now its solved ?

Comment: No i am not getting what is issue !

Comment: can you please help me ?..

Comment: Try to remove auto generated files from your folder and then reopen the project.

Comment: okay i will try it and tell you. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139774/discussion-between-megha-shah-and-rujul-gandhi).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139777/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-android-developer).

Answer (score 0):

Its working.... 
Yes after remove the auto generated files and reopen the project is working.

Thank you..